# What's wrong with my solution about Sqrt(x)

Tags: python

The webpage to test the code is here:
https://leetcode.com/problems/sqrtx/description/

I handed in these code and passed:

```
class Solution(object):
def mySqrt(self, x):
    """
    :type x: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    if x==1:
        return 1
    lowest=0.0
    uppest=x*1.0
    count=1
    middle=(lowest+uppest)*0.5
    while (abs(middle*middle-x)>0.001) and (count<=10000):
        if middle*middle>x:
            uppest=middle
        else:
            lowest=middle
        middle=(lowest+uppest)*0.5
        count=count+1
    return int(middle)
```

**but when I change**

```
while (abs(middle*middle-x)>0.001) and (count<=10000):
```

**into**

```
while (abs(middle*middle-x)>0.0001) and (count<=10000):
```

**or add more '0' like 0.00000000001 and use '9' as an input to test, it gets wrong**
**The output should be 3, but I got 2**

How can I solve this kind of problem while using the Bisection Method?
I don't want to use the library (I know that using library is the easiest way but I want to learn more)

Comment: I highlighted it

Comment: What is `middle` before you convert it to `int` and return it?

Comment: I removed int() and get 3.0. but when I add int(), it gets 2!

Comment: Yes, welcome to the infinite joys of floating point arithmetic.  Check out https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html to see what is really going on and https://bugs.python.org/issue1580 for why you're getting 3.0 and not 2.999....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is more like a math problem rather than python, just insert

```
print(middle,middle**2>x)
```

for debugging purposes.

```
class Solution(object):
    def mySqrt(self, x):
        """
        :type x: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        if x==1:
            return 1
        lowest=0.0
        uppest=x*1.0
        count=1
        middle=(lowest+uppest)*0.5
        while (abs(middle*middle-x)>0.0001) and (count<=10000):
            if middle*middle>x:
                uppest=middle
            else:
                lowest=middle
            middle=(lowest+uppest)*0.5
            count=count+1
            print(middle,middle**2>x)
        return int(middle)

sol=Solution()
print(sol.mySqrt(9))
```

The output

```
2.25 False
3.375 True
2.8125 False
3.09375 True
2.953125 False
3.0234375 True
2.98828125 False
3.005859375 True
2.9970703125 False
3.00146484375 True
2.999267578125 False
3.0003662109375 True
2.99981689453125 False
3.000091552734375 True
2.9999542236328125 False
3.0000228881835938 True
2.999988555908203 False
2
```

You can see the reason already.

Also I wonder why cannot you just use

```
round(middle)
```

Comment: Your advice was first and best, so this should be accepted. I fixed the last line to what OP (and I think you) meant.

Comment: @kabanus, thanks, I think it should be middle though, thus i changed.

Comment: Thanks, is that because of python only save the previous number but not rounding?

Comment: @kabanus: Indeed. OP is aware of but did not ask for a library function, and *this* is how to debug such code and zoom in on the problem.

Comment: @YilingLiu: as stated in other answers, `int(x)` rounds *down* (for positive numbers – the official term is "towards zero"). It is also mentioned in [the official documentation of `int()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html?highlight=truncate#int).

Comment: @YilingLiu `int(Afloat)` will truncate the `float`. Hence 2.9999 becomes `2`, but you meant for it to become `3`. The fact it was sometimes below 3 and sometimes above (and hence worked sometimes) was luck.

Answer (score 2):

The culprit is

```
return int(middle)
```

The reason you obtain 2 is because your are casting a number such as 2.99998855591 into int, which is the equivalent of `floor(x)`

After a number of iteration n0, the error `sqrt(x) - middle` between the target value and the value of middle follow a damped oscillation.

[image]
Just round to the closest integer instead
      return round(middle)

Comment: The `int` is redundant, since `round` return an `int`.

Comment: You get an upvote for the pretty, and informative, graph!

Answer (score 1):

See other answers for what is happening. The solution is:

```
return int(middle + 0.5)
```

which is rounding towards the nearest integer.

A bigger problem is of course that you're converting intermediate values to float when calculating an integer square root.  Floats have a very limited range compared to Python ints.  Try something like this instead:

```
def int_sqrt(n):
    """Return integer square root of integer ``n``.
    """
    x = n
    y = (x + 1) >> 1
    while y < x:
        x = y
        y = (x + n // x) >> 1
    return x
```

and e.g. run it on `int_sqrt(2**12345-1)` which should return a 1858 digit number.